# How to pass a complicated object array into Jade template?

Tags: pug

I have such jade snippt:

```
div.comment_list
    - var clist = comment_list
    each comment in clist
        div.comment
            div.comment_detail
                span.commentator comment.commentator
                span.comment_time comment.comment_time
                span.comment_content comment.comment_content
```

The `comment_list` is what I pass into the jade template.

The problem is :
Each array element `comment` consists of a compound object, which, as you saw,
has `commentator`, `comment_time`, and `comment_content`.

However, jade could not recognize this fact, and it just output : `comment.commentator` `comment.comment_time`, `comment.comment_content` vebatim.

So how to tackle this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to `- var` everything either. eg.

```
div.comment_list
    each comment in comment_list
        div.comment_detail
            span.commentator #{comment.commentator}
            span.comment_time #{comment.comment_time}
            span.comment_content #{comment.comment_content}
```

And if you are outputting a single variable, you do not need the `#{}` wrapper. It is only required if you are mixing plain text in there.

```
div.comment_list
    each comment in comment_list
        div.comment_detail
            span.commentator= comment.commentator
            span.comment_time= comment.comment_time
            span.comment_content= comment.comment_content
```

And the div's are redundant - you can simply us the `.class` or `#id` or both. Obviously, if you are not setting a class or id, you need to have the word `div` there.

```
.comment_list
    each comment in comment_list
        .comment_detail
            span.commentator= comment.commentator
            span.comment_time= comment.comment_time
            span.comment_content= comment.comment_content
```

Answer (score -1):

I have figured it out.

Let the code do the talking:

```
div.comment_list
    - var clist = comment_list
    each comment in clist
        - var commentator = comment.commentator
        - var comment_time = comment.comment_time
        - var comment_content = comment.comment_content
        div.comment_detail
            span.commentator #{commentator}
            span.comment_time #{comment_time}
            span.comment_content #{comment_content}
```